# Create mark-links on the areas(polygons)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a some issue with my map. I need to show some marks on each area(polygon) like here https://www.foxtons.co.uk/living-in (WD, N, EN, E...) and it have to be links on other pages. But I can't find to decide this issue. And I don't know how I can take a future object in function styleFeature, that take his center. Thanks.

It is my code map:

```
var mapStyle = [{
    'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}]
}, {
    'featureType': 'landscape',
    'elementType': 'geometry',
    'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}]
}, {
    'featureType': 'water',
    'elementType': 'geometry',
    'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#bfd4ff'}]
}];
var map;
function initMap() {
// load the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 55.864237, lng: -4.251806},
        zoom: 12,
        styles: mapStyle
    });
// set up the style rules and events for google.maps.Data
    map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
    map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseInToRegion);
    map.data.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutOfRegion);
    map.data.addListener('click', mouseClickOfRegion);
// state polygons only need to be loaded once, do them now
    loadMapShapes();
}
function loadMapShapes() {
// load US state outline polygons from a GeoJson file
    map.data.loadGeoJson('http://165.227.72.239/wp-content/themes/realty-child/js/regions.js', { idPropertyName: 'STATE' });
}
function styleFeature(feature) {
    var low = [5, 69, 54]; // color of smallest datum
    var high = [151, 83, 34]; // color of largest datum
    var color = '';
    var colored = '#078e05';
// determine whether to show this shape or not
    var showRow = true;
    var outlineWeight = 1.5, zIndex = 1;
    if (feature.getProperty('state') === 'hover') {
        outlineWeight = zIndex = 2;
        colored = '#92ce90';
    }
    var poly = {
        strokeWeight: outlineWeight,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        zIndex: zIndex,
        fillColor: colored,
        fillOpacity: 0.75,
        visible: showRow
    };
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getAt(0).getArray();
    return poly;
}
function mouseInToRegion(e) {
// set the hover state so the setStyle function can change the border
    e.feature.setProperty('state', 'hover');

}

function mouseOutOfRegion(e) {
// reset the hover state, returning the border to normal
    e.feature.setProperty('state', 'normal');
}
function mouseClickOfRegion(e) {
// reset the click state, returning the border to normal
    e.feature.setProperty('click', 'normal');

    map.setZoom(13);
    map.setCenter(e.latLng);
    map.data.overrideStyle(e.feature,{fillColor:'transparent'});
}
initMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add a marker with a link at the center of a polygon.

This function will get you the center of a polygon:

```
function getPolygonCenter(polygon) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
    var paths  = polygon.getPaths()

    // loop through each path of the polygon
    for (var i = 0, i_end = paths.length; i < i_end; i++) {
        var path = paths.getAt(i)

        // loop through each LatLng pair of the path
        for (var j = 0, j_end = path.getLength(); j < j_end; j++) {

            // extend the bounds
            bounds.extend(path.getAt(j))
        }
    }

    // return the center of the bounds
    return bounds.getCenter()
}
```

This function will create a custom marker with a link:

```
function createMarkerWithLink(position, url, icon, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : position,
        url      : url,
        icon     : icon,
        map      : map
    });

    // add click event that opens marker's url
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = this.url;
    });

    return marker;
}
```

**EDIT**

After looking at the **[docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)** for the `Data Class` it looks like you can provide a callback to `loadGeoJson` or you can call `forEach` on the data class after the polygons have been created.

This is how you can access the polygons created by the `loadGeoJson` method:

```
function loadMapShapes() {
    // load US state outline polygons from a GeoJson file
    var urlString = 'http://165.227.72.239/wp-content/themes/realty-child/js/regions.js';
    var options   = { idPropertyName: 'STATE' };
    var callback  = function(arrFeatures) {
        for (var i = 0, i_end = arrFeatures.length; i < i_end; i++) {
            var feature = arrFeatures[i];
            // do stuff with polygon
        }
    };

    map.data.loadGeoJson(url, options, callback);
}
```

This would be how you would use the `forEach` method:

```
loadMapShapes();

// would need to be called after the polygons had been created
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    // do stuff with polygon here
});
```

Comment: I found those functions, but I don't know how can I take a future object in function styleFeature? When I write `getPolygonCenter(poly);` in console I have this error: `Uncaught TypeError: polygon.getPaths is not a function`
And I don't know how can I do custom marker look like that site(like some text with border)?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: polygon.getPaths is not a function` means that the poly you passed in is not a `google.maps.Polygon`.

As far as the custom marker, I'm guessing that website is using a custom icon which you can supply when you create the marker. [Here is google's example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers)

Comment: Thanks. I load my polygons data with loadGeoJson function and after that in styleFeature function I add style for each polygon 
`var poly = {
        strokeWeight: outlineWeight,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        zIndex: zIndex,
        fillColor: colored,
        fillOpacity: 0.75,
        visible: showRow
    };`
but how I can take polygon object to get his center?

Comment: Okay I got you. When you call `map.data.loadGeoJson` it should return the polygons it created. If you could run `console.log(loadMapShapes())` and tell me what it returns I can try to help you.

Comment: It return 'undefined'